# Tableau month over month growth and Top and bottom result

Tags: tableau-api

[image]I have Order date,Segment and sales Column on my Tableau database. I need Top and bottom 5 segment wise month over month growth on sales.

[image: Requirement]

[image: Summary]

As per my requirement i have attached the snapshot for your reference.

Comment: People will be able to assist you better if you post a short simple set of data, just a few rows and columns, enough to clearly illustrate your question, and the result you hope to achieve for that sample data. Maybe simplify to the top 1 or 2 for brevity.

Comment: There are some Tableau features that can help with this problem, or related problems. I suggest learning about the Top and Condition tabs on filters, Sets and Table Calcs, including table calc filters. Depending on the circumstances, you’ll likely use some combination of these - probably table calc filters in your case. Realize table calcs take a while to learn, but are useful. If you have very large data sets, you might also want to learn about analytic or window queries in SQL, which you can use with Tableau via custom SQL. Lots to learn ...